# For request in operation UploadPhotoStream to be a stream the operation must have a single parameter whose type is Stream

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, soap

I've been searching this issue but still unable to find exact solution.

Code:

```
namespace StackSample.Logic
{
    [ServiceHeaderBehavior]
    [MerchantHeaderBehavior]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class Merchant : Interfaces.IMerchant
    {
        public bool UploadPhotoStream(string productid, string photoid, Stream fileData)
        {
            Logic.Components.Product ca = new Logic.Components.Product();
            return ca.UploadPhotoStream(Common.UserValues().Merchant, productid, photoid, fileData);
        }
    }
}

namespace StackSample.Interfaces
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IMerchant
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "UploadPhotoStream?productid={productid}&photoid={photoid}", Method = "POST")]
        bool UploadPhotoStream(string productid, string photoid, Stream fileData);
    }
}
```

Config:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="SOAPSecure">
      <security mode="None" />
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="2097152" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="2097152" />
    </binding>
    <binding name="SOAPSecureTransfer" transferMode="Streamed" closeTimeout="00:05:00" openTimeout="00:05:00" receiveTimeout="00:15:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Mtom" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="RESTSecure">
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="RESTSecureTransfer" transferMode="Streamed" closeTimeout="00:05:00" openTimeout="00:05:00" receiveTimeout="00:15:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<!-- behaviors -->
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="JSON">
      <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="Default">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="true" includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />


<services>  
  <service behaviorConfiguration="Default" name="StackSample.Logic.Merchant">
    <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SOAPSecureTransfer" contract="StackSample.Interfaces.IMerchant" />
    <endpoint address="rest" behaviorConfiguration="JSON" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="RESTSecureTransfer" contract="StackSample.Interfaces.IMerchant" />
  </service>
</services>
```

When I try to run `http://localhost:64039/Merchant/Merchant.svc`
It shows an error:

```
For request in operation UploadPhotoStream to be a stream the operation must have a single parameter whose type is Stream.
```

I don't have any idea on what to do.

Comment: What part of the error message don't you understand?

Comment: @JohnSaunders I can't understand why it doesn't accept multiple parameters. Because I have seen a project that have this kind of UriTemplate and it accepts multiple parameters including the stream. I just did the same config and formatting, except that my wcf is using `svc` file, while the project I have seen was using WCF 4.0 REST template, it doesn't have `svc` files.

Comment: You say there's no difference between the two project types - except for the difference. Chances are, that difference accounts for the difference in behavior.

Comment: That's exactly what the error message is telling you!

Comment: John Saunders: no, the error message says nothing about REST templates or svc files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For future viewers, if you want to achieve this goal, wherein you will be able to put multiple parameters together with `Stream`, what you need to do is to avoid using `SVC` files to create Rest or Soap service. Instead add this on your services project, `Global.asax` file, the make route table, like for example:

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("MyApp/rest/Photo", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(PhotoComponent)));
}
```

**In your web service:**

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class PhotoComponent : Interfaces.IPhotoComponent
{
    public bool UploadPhotoStream(string productid, string photoid, Stream fileData)
    {
        // some code....
    }
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface PhotoComponent
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "UploadPhotoStream/{productid}/{photoid}", Method = "POST")]
    bool UploadPhotoStream(string productid, string photoid, System.IO.Stream fileData);
}
```

**inside web.config:**

```
<services>  
  <service behaviorConfiguration="Default" name="StackSample.Logic.PhotoComponent">
    <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="JSON" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="RESTSecureTransfer" contract="StackSample.Interfaces.PhotoComponent" />
  </service>
</services>
```

**and call it:**

```
https://127.0.0.1/MyApp/rest/Photo/UploadPhotoStream/{productid}/{photoid}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Not able to add "RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("MyApp/rest/Photo", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(PhotoComponent)));" and I need the solution.

Answer (score 4):

You need to have a single parameter in your operation that takes in an object that contains properties that you need.

See code below for example:

```
public interface IMerchant
{
    bool UploadPhotoStream(UploadData request);
}

public class YourService : IMerchant
{
    public bool UploadPhotoStream(UploadData request)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class UploadData
{
    [DataMember]
    string ProductId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    string PhotoId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    System.IO.Stream FileData { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I have seen this solution before. If I won't be able to do the task without using class, I will go to this approach.

Comment: I couldn't understand your solution! I want to make it a POST request and I need to have File Name with it.

Comment: @Chris Holwerda, Thank you for your short logic.

Answer (score 0):

You should configure the service the following way in the web.config. Then you're able to send a Stream with further URL Parameters. The Stream parameter should be the last parmater in the function.

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="YourServiceClassWithNamespace">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingWithJSON" contract="YourServiceInterfaceWithNamespace" behaviorConfiguration="EndpointBehavior" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJSON" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864"
             openTimeout="00:10:00" closeTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00">
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="EndpointBehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```